# Why appear, appearance are spelled with "ea", but apparent, apparently are spelled with "a"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

For the word appear, the verb and noun are spelled with "ea", but the adverb and adjective are spelled with "a", why do they have different vowels given that they have the same root?

Verb:      app***ea***r,
noun: app***ea***rance

While

Adjective: app***a***rent and not app***ea***rent?

Comment: Are you asking about the same effect  as we see in similar Latinate  pairs like *explain/explanation* and *inspire/inspiration*? If so, then we have many duplicates whose answers all answer your question. If not, then how does  your question differ substantially from all of  those others?

Comment: @tchrist I don't understand what the examples you provided are hinting at/should demonstrate. I tried looking up questions entailing the examples, but couldn't find any, could you please give a link to one of such answered questions and then I can tell whether my question is of the same type.